# How to save model weights in tf keras when training on TPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tpu

I want to save weights of a model I trained on kaggle's TPUs, but I'm getting an error. Its a known bug and one work around is saving the weights to cpu from the TPU. Is there any other workaround this bug?

Answer (score 1):

From Tensorflow 2.3 and tf-nightly you can use [tf.saved_model.LoadOptions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/LoadOptions) with tf.saved_model.LoadOptions="/job:localhost" to save/restorer a TPU model on local file system:

```
model_dir = "./mnist_model"

localhost_save_option = tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(experimental_io_device="/job:localhost")
model.save(model_dir, options=localhost_save_option)

# Restore the weights
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir, options=localhost_save_option)
```

Comment: how would i change experimental_io_device="/job:localhost" for windows

Comment: If you are running on windows (with or without GPUs attached) you likely won't need to provide `experimental_io_device`. `model.save(model_dir)` and `tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir)` should work for saving and loading a model.

Comment: i was able to bypass this entire experimental_io_device by loading my model by ensuring that i was calling tensorflow_text. I spent 2 hours breaking my head. finally this solved it. thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Whereismywall how were you able to bypass "experimental_io_device" on windows